# Selective/Combined Type Hints (Literals etc.)

Tags: python, type-hinting

Is it possible to combine (perhaps not the right word) two or more sets of type hints such that they are only valid in specific combinations?

I have a function that takes `value` and `value_type` arguments. (these later get fed into a graphQL API where I use both values to set up filtering in a query string i.e. `"endpoint(value_type: value) {...}"`so I need to separately know both items)

`value_type` is already typed as `Literal["option1", "option2", "secret third option"]`

`value` could be either an `int` or a `str`, which currently I'm just typing as `Union[int, str]` which is fine for just me because I wrote it, obviously, but if others use this library I'd like it to be more clear:

What I want is more dynamic, e.g. a `value_type` of `"option1"` **must** have a value given as a `str`, whereas `"option2"` must come with an `int`, etc.

Currently I just use a match/case and some `assert`s to validate, but I'd prefer for the IDE to indicate there's a problem before you run it without writing some hefty documentation.

I'm against making two functions as the rest of the code is identical, it just adds some quote marks if its a string to satisfy graphQL query formatting.

Comment: That sounds like a job for `@typing.overload`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typing.overload` for that. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload.

To use it, write your function without annotations then add definitions for all combinations with the decorator `@typing.overload`.

```
@typing.overload
def function(value: str, value_type: Literal["option1"]) -> str:
    ...

@typing.overload
def function(value: int, value_type: Literal["option2"]) -> int:
    ...

def function(value, value_type):
    if value_type == "option1":
        return value + "1"
    elif value_type == "option2":
        return value + 1
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```

I am not sure why you need `value_type`. If you don't need it, you can use a `Union` for `value` and your static type checker should be able to narrow the type inside the match/case.

Comment: "value_type" in reality will be strings of their own e.g. things like "username" or "id" for use in the API I'm using, not the actual type in the variable-type sense. Beyond that thank you for the answer!! Always thought overloading in python wasn't a thing! god bless typing!